# Is there a way to monitor DDL statements? Like a Stream on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried to create a stream on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS view but that was refused because it is a BUILT-IN View rather than a view.

I would like to monitor all DDL statements and trigger some processing, like a TASK or Stored procedure

Comment: You could write a SP to do this and then run the SP from a task at a suitable interval

Comment: True but I was hoping to find some way to trigger this automatically on change, rather than on schedule